# Mapping Wordpress.com to subdomain or path

Tags: redirect, subdomain, wordpress, redirection

According to [this](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/redirecting-your-blog/) and [this](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/), Wordpress.com blogs can be mapped to a custom domain (e.g.: example.com).  However, I don't see anything that says it can be mapped to a subdomain (e.g.: blog.example.com) or a path within a domain (e.g.: example.com/blog).

Does anyone have any experience with this to definitively say whether this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible, I think you just missed this link that shows how:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-subdomain/

Comment: Thanks for the link! To clarify for anyone else who has the same question, that link explains that it *can* be done with subdomains, but *cannot* be done with subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I've actually did this unintetionally earlier, I unzipped the wordpress .zip to my folder and uploaded it, which gave me example.com/wordpress. You could easily rename the folder to blog or similar and this would provide the desired effect.